# Updating a DIV box from controller using AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am going to update a small chat between two users every minute. This is already working - however I can't figure how to do an AJAX call to update the DIV containing the actual messages.

```
var interval
window.onload = function(){
    interval = setInterval('updateMessages()', 2000);
};

function updateMessages() {
    $(function () {
         // UPDATE #mail_container
    });
}
```

What´d be a proper way approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to include jQuery and make use of either its .append() or .html() methods.

eg. `$("#mail_container").html("<p>Your chat message</p>");`

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/append/
- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I've gotten that far, but how do I get the data from the controller?

Comment: The jquery ajax function will let you do that - see the link @swatkins provided. When you call that function you can specify a codeigniter url in the same way you're used to eg. with the /controller/function/arguments format.